# How to fix exposed Firebase Cloud Messaging (FCM) server keys before my app gets removed from Play Store?

Tags: java, firebase, android-studio

I have an app on Play Store. I am using Firebase Cloud Messaging for sending Notifications to users. Yesterday, I got email from Google that my key is exposed and I need to fix it or my app will be removed from Play Store by 11 January. Please explain how can I fix this in simple language.

Answer (score -1):

Log into your firebase console and create a new server key by pressing add server key and replacing it with the old one.

[image: Firebase console]

Comment: This isn't enough. One still needs to be able to retrieve the new key without embedding it in the app. You don't explain how to do that.